# Changing AlertDialog text color and size on older Android version (2.3.3)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I am developing small Android application, in which I want to customize `AlertDialog`. For that I created my style for `AlertDialog` in following way:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="dialog">
    <item name="android:fullDark">@drawable/dialog_title</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@drawable/dialog_title</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@drawable/dialog_body</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@drawable/dialog_footer</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@drawable/dialog_body</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@drawable/dialog_body</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@drawable/dialog_footer</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@drawable/dialog_footer</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@drawable/dialog_body</item>
</style>
```

And I am applying this theme to my `AlertDialog` in following way:

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MyTheme);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
```

But I am not able to change header title text color and its size on older version of Android (2.3.3). How to do this?